# Trying to get a Python script together to email me a week of events at the start of every week

Tags: python, calendar, gmail, google-calendar-api

Problem:

So far I've created the following code which emails me an attachment, I want it to email me my calendar with up to 7 days of events every Monday.

How would I go about doing this?

Example:
I log on to my email on Monday morning, and I have an email in my gmail inbox. within that email there should be a list of events I have in the next 7 days;

Monday - relax
Tuesday - Work

ETC...

I want this to be pulled from Google calendars.

Code:

```
import smtplib
from email.mime.text import MIMEText
from email.mime.multipart import MIMEMultipart
from email.mime.base import MIMEBase
from email import encoders

email_user = 'your_email'
email_password = 'your_password'
email_send = 'recipient_email'

subject = 'subject'

msg = MIMEMultipart()
msg['From'] = email_user
msg['To'] = email_send
msg['Subject'] = subject

body = 'Hi there, sending this email from Python!'
msg.attach(MIMEText(body,'plain'))

filename='filename'
attachment  =open(filename,'rb')

part = MIMEBase('application','octet-stream')
part.set_payload((attachment).read())
encoders.encode_base64(part)
part.add_header('Content-Disposition',"attachment; filename= "+filename)

msg.attach(part)
text = msg.as_string()
server = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.gmail.com',587)
server.starttls()
server.login(email_user,email_password)


server.sendmail(email_user,email_send,text)
server.quit()
```

Comment: You can use the gmail calendar API. Have a look there, give it a try, and update what you've attempted please: https://developers.google.com/calendar/quickstart/python

Comment: Can you not just run your script from a crontab (or whatever it's called if on a Windows platform) every Monday?